# chrome.webRequest.onResponseStarted.addListener

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In Manifest added these lines

```
permissions": [ "tabs","webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "http://*/*", "https://*/*","ftp://*/*","contextMenus","proxy","cookies"],
```

and my chrome version is 21.0.1180.89
i tried to use the chrome api in background.js page

```
var callbackFunction = function(details){
alert("response started ");
}

chrome.webRequest.onResponseStarted.addListener(callbackFunction);
```

but i am getting following error

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onResponseStarted' of undefined"
```

Comment: 1: Is your manifest correct? (Show the *whole* file, your current line doesn't show any problems). 2: Did you really put that code in the background page?

Comment: <rant> At the time of writing this the [google documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onResponseStarted) was demonstrably inaccurate and misleading </rant>